# How to release memory for declared object in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, memory-management

I'm facing small problem,

I declare an array in .h file and allocate it in `viewDodLoad` method. In `dealloc` method I check if array not equal to `nil` then `array=nil`. But it's crashing in iOS 5.1.1. I can't understand reason for this crash.

My code,

```
   @interface SampleApp : UIViewController
   {
        NSMutableArray *objArray;
   }
   @end

   @implementation SampleApp

   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
        [super viewDidLoad]; 
        objArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   }
   -(void)dealloc
   {
      [super dealloc];
      if (objArray!=nil)
     {
         [objArray removeAllObjects];
         [objArray release];objArray=nil;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `[super dealloc];` at the end of `dealloc` method and not at beginning. It is recommended by Apple in its [documentation for `dealloc` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-dealloc).

> When not using ARC, your implementation of dealloc must invoke the superclass’s implementation as its last instruction.

Modify your code as below,

```
   -(void)dealloc
   {
      if (objArray!=nil)
     {
         [objArray removeAllObjects];
         [objArray release];objArray=nil;
     }
      [super dealloc];
   }
```

Also, you need not call `[objArray removeAllObjects]` when you are releasing the entire array. When array is released, internally it will call `release` on all contained objects.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

**[super dealloc]** method must be call in end of this method. Because you can not access variables of the superclass anymore because they are released when you call [super dealloc]. It is always safe to call the superclass in the last line.

```
-(void)dealloc
   {

// ----------- your stuff ------------

      [super dealloc];

  }
```

Comment: Thank You @ Dharmir Choudary

Answer (score 0):

With *manual memory management*,  your -dealloc method looks as follows:

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [objArray release];   // objArray *may* be nil, and this is 
                          // sufficient to release all elements as well.

    // call super at the end  
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Additionally, you have a potential memory leak in your method `-viewDidLoad`. If you do it like your example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    objArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
```

you *may* assign `objArray` a new pointer even if `objArray` already holds a valid object. The new pointer value will simply override the old, and thus you cannot release the old anymore.

One way is to check whether `objArray` is not `nil` and then release it before assigning it a new value:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    if (objArray) {
        [objArray release], objArray = nil;
    }
    objArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
```

The better approach however is to employ "lazy initializing properties":

First, define an "internal property" for your array (unless you want the array publicly accessible). In your .m file:

```
// In your implementation file define a private property in a class extension:   
@interface SampleApp ()
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray* objArray;       
@end


@implementation SampleApp

@synthesize objArray = _objArray;   // this will create the setter

-(void)dealloc
{
    [_objArray release];
    [super dealloc];
}

// Lazy init property:   (this is the getter)
- (NSMutableArray*) objArray {
    if (_objArray == nil) {
        _objArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return _objArray;
}

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]; 

    // When needing the array, simply *and always* access it 
    // through the property "self.objArray":
    NSUInteger count = [self.objArray count];
}

...
```

Lazy initialization of properties are quite handy. Basically, you won't worry anymore if they are initialized or not - they simply are, when you use the property accessor.